# ShellOS pacman cannot find database file (Arch derivative)

Tags: arch-linux, upgrade, pacman, database

Currently running theShell OS 7.0 (Arch variant) on a VM. I went to update the software (as this version is several years out of date) and `pacman` just spat this out:

```
~ $ Welcome, user. Enter command: pacman -Uv
warning: database file for 'theapps' does not exist
Error: you cannot perform this operation unless you are root.
```

I understand that I have to run it as root, but the focus is this database file. How do I fix the problem or find the file?

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you get the same error as root? What command did you run? Was it `pacman -Uv` or something else? What happens with `sudo pacman -Suy`?